# Faults in the halting problem reasoning

Tags: turing-machines, halting-problem

I find very interesting the problem of existence of a machine $H$ which given as input any algorithm $P$ outputs whether $P$ halts or not. Alan Turing disproved the existence of such an $H$ machine in the following way:

"Assume $H$ exists. The input of $H$ is any algorithm $P$. The output of $H$ is $YES$ if $P$ halts and $NO$ if $P$ doesn't. Create another machine $N$ with input in the set $\{YES,NO\}$ and without output. The machine $N$ does this: if the input is $YES \to \text{loop for ever}$ otherwise, if input is $NO \to \text{halt}$. Let us call the composition of $H$ followed by $N$ as $X$. We will simply write $X(P) = N(H(P))$. Now $X$ has as input a machine and no output (it either halts or loops forever). What Turing does is to "feed" $X$ with itself ... and reason as follows: if $X(X)$ halts then $X(X) = N(H(X)) = N(YES) = \text{loops for ever}$ from which somehow the contradiction arises ..." but here one should assume (in order to obtain a contradiction) that $X(X) = X$ ...

### Question

I do not know why such an assumption, $X = X(X)$ would be made. In fact, in my opinion, $X \neq X(X)$ for any input $P$ (that is all Turing is proving actually). Indeed assume $P$ is a machine which halts (runs for ever). Then $X(P)$ does not halt (does halt) when $X(X(P))$ does (does not). I do not understand therefore, why $H$ cannot exist! Where is my mistake ?

Comment: Your transcription of the proof has several errors. It confuses $A_0$, $A_1$ and $A_2$ in several places. Would you like me to fix it? (I would start by not calling these $A_0$, $A_1$ and $A_2$, as that is quite unreadable.)

Comment: sure, please go ahead ... I will change back if I consider that the essence of the question was lost though!

Comment: In the meanwhile, you might find it helpful to watch this [excellent video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=92WHN-pAFCs) about Halting Problem.

Comment: I have seen the video already ... I think it glides over the core of my concerns expressed here in this question ...

Comment: @andrejBauer I do not think I confused $A_0, A_1, A_2$ anywhere though ... and $A$ stands for algorithm. Why you think is unreadable ?

Comment: I named the machines the same way that they are in the video. You state that somehow one need $X(X) = X$, but that does not make any sense: the left-hand side is the result of running $X$ with input $X$, but the right-hand side is a machine. We cannot compare the result (in this case termination or looping) with a machine.

Comment: Hmm, my point is that $X $ and $X(X)$ are different algorithms ... If somehow I would be convinced that, due to some other reason,  also $X = X(X)$ then it would follow $X = \emptyset$ hence $X$ does not exist.

Comment: Actually $X, X(X)$ are both algorithms needing an algorithm as input ... Yes, this is actually the key of my understanding ... I see  them as functions which need an input.

Comment: Please allow me to continue my reasoning here: I would expect a class of algorithms ,say $\mathcal{P}$ which can be executed/started. Then on these algorithms one can run $X$.

Comment: I now see what bothers you. The problem is that the proof you wrote is actually wrong (it uses the wrong definition of the halting oracle). Where did you find it? I wrote up the correct proof. It is precisely the proof from the video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof you wrote in the question is faulty, because it uses the wrong definition of the Halting oracle. You tried to fix the proof by inserting the assumption $X(X) = X$, but that is not the way to do it. Here is the correct proof.

**Definition:** A *halting oracle* is a machine $H$ which takes as input a pair  $(M,I)$ where $M$ is the (description of) a machine and $I$ an input. $H$ always  halts and outputs:

- "yes" if $M(I)$ halts,
- "no" if $M(I)$ does not halt.

**Theorem:** *A halting oracle does not exist.*

*Proof.* Suppose $H$ exists. We shall derive a contradiction.

Let $N$ be a machine which does the following upon receiving an input $I$:

- if $I$ is "yes" then $N$ loops forever,
- otherwise $N$ halts.

Let $X$ be the machine which takes an input $I$ and then acts as $N(H(I, I))$. We now prove two contradictory facts:

1. $X(X)$ does not halt.
2. $X(X)$ halts.

To prove the first claim, suppose $X(X)$ halts. Then $H(X,X)$ outputs "yes", therefore $X(X) = N(H(X,X)) = N(\text{yes})$, but $N(\text{yes})$ does not halt. Therefore it is not true that $X(X)$ halts.

To prove the second claim, suppose $X(X)$ does not halt. Then $H(X,X)$ outputs "no", therefore $X(X) = N(H(X,X)) = N(\text{no})$, but $N(\text{no})$ halts. Therefore it is not true that $X(X)$ does not halt, so it halts. $\Box$.

Comment: would you agree with defining the oracle $H$ as $H(M(I)) \in \{ YES, NO\}$ with obvious choice of yes and no ? Then $X(I) = N(H(I(I)))$ and $X(X) = N(H(X(X)))$ through definition.

Comment: I would not. The halting oracle takes **two** inputs: a machine and the input to be fed to the machine, and you need to explain what $H$ does withour referring to $H$ (because you are trying to define $H$). But you are suggesting that we should define what $H$ does on input $(M,I)$ by saying that it does $H(M(I))$ - this is not a valid definition because you referred to $H$. And also, $H(M(I))$ is wrong because $H$ takes two inputs, but  "$M(I)$" is just a single input (namely the output of $M$ when run with intput $I$).

Comment: ok but why wouldn't you agree that for any halting oracle $H: \{machines\} \times \{ inputs\} \to \{Y,N\}$ you can consider a function $\bar{H}: \{ machines\} \to \{Y,N\}$. Since $M(I)$ is a machine still, we define $\bar{H}(M(I)) = H(M,I)$ (for those other machines $M^{0}$, which can not written as $M(I)$ consider $M^{0} = M^{0}(\emptyset)$ ) Now I wonder if $H(M, \emptyset)$ is defined actually ?

Comment: $H(M, \emptyset)$ is actually trivial to define $H(M,\emptyset) = YES$ if $M$ halts and $H(M, \emptyset) = NO$ if it doesn't. I have therefore "converted" your definition of oracle to mine, haven't I ?

Comment: When you write $H(M(I))$ that does not make sense. You must write $H(M,I)$. When you write $\emptyset$ as input, you are confusing the *type* of input and its value, so $H(M, \emptyset)$ makes no sense. What does it mean that the input to a machine is the empty set? It has to be something written on a tape.

Comment: Well, first thank you for keep answering! You see, I haven't studied Turing machines before. My background is in other kind of mathematics and programming. However, there are programs which do not have inputs, isn't it? They can be quite useful! Like that looping machine for instance!

Comment: Actually I was thinking to write a question, about halting oracles for machines without inputs! It seems to me that the above proof should not work for those ...

Comment: Every machine has input (that's how machines are defined). The "no input" can be modelled either as "the machine ignores its input" or "input is any element from the set $\{c\}$" where $c$ is some pre-determined constant. If you say that the input is an element of $\emptyset$ then you cannot run the machine, because you cannot give it any input to run on.

Comment: Ok, I do not know why is this redundancy necessary, but, still, for such "machines" the above prove would not work since if we discuss the existence of a halting oracle for such "machines/programs" the above proof goes like this: define $H : \{ machines\} \times \{c\} \to \{Y,N\}$ hence we cannot use $H(X,X)$ ... I am too vague ? I am afraid so !

Comment: It is not redundancy. Every machine takes input, just like every function does. Then we do not have to consider all the time the special case of "machines without inputs".